# Android : How to get users general location without special permissions

Tags: android, android-location

I do not want to track my users. I just would like to know where in the world my users are accessing my app from. is there a way I can get the users location without scaring them off with permissions for COURSE or FINE locations?

I am already using the android.permission.INTERNET permission to request data from my server is there anyway I can leverage that?

if not I guess I could always use the request to the server to locate the user.

Comment: On the server side, using the client IP could get you some information about the users location. Or the preferred language from the browser could give a hint.

Comment: Yeah that will probably be the better option, I was just curious to see if there was another way.